# Volume shared between two containers "is busy or locked"

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment that runs two containers. One of the containers attempts to build (during deployment) a javascript bundle that the other container, nginx, tries to serve.

I want to use a shared volume to place the javascript bundle after it's built.

So far, I have the following deployment file (with irrelevant pieces removed):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: personal-site
        image: wheresmycookie/personal-site:3.1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: build-volume
          mountPath: /var/app/dist
      - name: nginx-server
        image: nginx:1.19.0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: build-volume
          mountPath: /var/app/dist
      volumes:
      - name: build-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

To the best of my ability, I have followed these guides:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

One other things to point out is that I'm trying to run this locally atm using `minikube`.

EDIT: The Dockerfile I used to build this image is:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /var/app

COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli@latest

CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

I realize that I do not need to build this when I actually run the image, but my next goal is to insert pod instance information as environment variables, so with javascript unfortunately I can only build once that information is available to me.

### Problem

The logs from the `personal-site` container reveal:

```
-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/var/app/dist'
 Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/var/app/dist'
```

I'm not sure why the build is trying to remove `/dist`, but also have a feeling that this is irrelevant. I could be wrong?

I thought that maybe this could be related to the lifecycle of containers/volumes, but the docs suggest that "An emptyDir volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a Node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node".

### Question

What are some reasons that a volume might not be available to me after the containers are already running? Given that you probably have much more experience than I do with Kubernetes, what would you look into next?

Comment: Why not run this build sequence in your image's Dockerfile, once only at build time, instead of re-running it once per replica and re-running it again if the pod happens to get restarted?

Comment: The `rmdir '/var/app/dist'` probably doesn't look necessary, but as far as the build sequence is concerned, that step fails (since something is mounted on that directory, it can't be removed) and once the step is failed the build is done.  A more complete description of what exactly the `wheresmycookie/personal-site:3.1` image does would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidMaze I was curious to insert information about the pod instances in the javascript builds, that's all. I'll update the question to include the Dockerfile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to customize your image's entrypoint as following:

- Once you finish building the `/var/app/dist` folder, copy(or move) this folder to another empty path (.e.g: `/opt/dist`)

  ```
  cp -r /var/app/dist/* /opt/dist
  ```

PAY ATTENTION: this Step must be done in the script of ENTRYPOINT not in the RUN layer.

- Now use `/opt/dist` instead..:

  ```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    ...
  spec:
    ...
    template:
      ...
      spec:
        hostNetwork: true
        containers:
        - name: personal-site
          image: wheresmycookie/personal-site:3.1
          volumeMounts:
          - name: build-volume
            mountPath: /opt/dist # <--- make it consistent with image's entrypoint algorithm
        - name: nginx-server
          image: nginx:1.19.0
          volumeMounts:
          - name: build-volume
            mountPath: /var/app/dist

        volumes:
        - name: build-volume
          emptyDir: {}
  ```

Good luck!

If it's not clear how to customize the entrypoint, share with us your entrypoint of the image and we will implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will give this a try now and upvote if it works. It's still not clear to me though why I am getting this error and why this solution would work. Could you please elaborate a little more there? Thank you

Comment: Go inside the container of the pod, run `df -h` and you will see what are the busy devices :)

Comment: Thank you! It seems like the "build" command was somehow trying to remove the volume - your suggestion worked perfectly!